# Is it possible to know the result of a match between three teams with only knowing their goals for and goals against?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle, word-problem

I've found this problem in my book and left clueless on how to make the right interpretation to come up with a solution. The situation involves a hockey match. Typically when you have a goals for and goals against table you already know the results of the match. But what is the recommended procedure when you don't?.

The problem is as follows:

> A tv reporter covering the results of a hockey match group stages for
>   the Summer Universiade in Taipei forgot to write down the results of each
>   match. There were three teams involved, Netherlands, France and
>   Norway. Before airing her segment on the news, she remembered to have
>   a handwritten notes of the goals for and goals against between the
>   teams mentioned. This table is shown in the diagram from below. The
>   reporter tells the viewers that the three teams have played only once
>   against each other and each team has played only two matches. If the
>   only available footage shown on tv tells the match between France and
>   Norway ended in a draw. What was the result of the match between
>   Netherlands and Norway?.

[image: Diagram of the problem]

The alternatives given were as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&3-1\\
2.&2-1\\
3.&3-2\\
4.&1-3\\
5.&4-3\\
\end{array}$

In this particular situation I don't know where to begin. As I mentioned in the opening statement of this question. My doubt arises from the fact that the results from each match is not known and only the one which is known is the one between France and Norway. Does it exist a way to uncover or unhide this from what is known?. I tried to make an equation, but then I figured out. What can I label $x$ ?.

Upon examination what I could come up with was to know that the only existing combinations between these three are:

Netherland - France

Netherland - Norway

France - Norway

From the goals for it is only known that each team did scored that amount of goals across the entire phase (I suppose that). So at this moment it is not known what exactly the match ended for each team.

I assumed:

For the goals scored in the match:

$\textrm{Netherlands - France = x}$

$\textrm{Netherlands - Norway = y}$

$x+y = 5$

For the goals received in the match:

$\textrm{Netherlands - France = a}$

$\textrm{Netherlands - Norway = b}$

$a+b = 5$

But at this point I got confused on how to use previous information. I suspect that the goals one received accounts for what other has made. But I don't know how to put this piece together with the fact of the draw between the teams as given in the clue from the problem.

Can somebody help me in the right direction for this problem?. I think an answer which would help me the most would be one which can be very detailed in step by step to put the pieces together. Not just solving the problem but more like teaching what should be found first and build that from there. Overall can somebody help me to find an answer for this problem the most easiest way possible?.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very nice question.

Let's start with the known fact that France vs Norway ended in a draw. And let's say that draw is of a score of $a : a$.

Then we know the Netherlands vs France game's result must be: $6-a : 7-a$ since the total goal for France is 7 and goal against is 6.

Similarly, we get that Netherlands vs Norway ended in $5-a:4-a$.

Lastly, we know the goals for Netherlands is $5 = 5 - a + 6 - a$. Therefore, $a=3$ and you can solve for the score of Netherlands vs Norway $2:1$.

Comment: It's a delight the simplicity of your method. It appears to be that the key was to begin from the clue given at the beginning. Just as I mentioned I didn't know how to use it. I also believe that to use Netherlands as a pivot to compare the results helps a lot. This approach works well with three teams. How about four, can this method be extended? or will that require additional variables?.

Comment: I would be interested in trying to solve a similar problem with more than 3 teams. Depending on the given information, this approach might or might not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat different approach, without algebraic equations.

We see that France and Norway together scored $7+411$ goals. All these goals were either in the France-Norway game, or they were scored against the Netherlands.  Since we know $5$ were scored against the Netherlands, we see $6$ were scored in the France-Norway game, which must have ended in a $3-3$ tie.

France scored $7$ goals, and $3$ of them were scored against Norway; the other $4$ were scored against the Netherlands. Similarly, $6$ goals were scored against France, $3$ by Norway, so the Netherlands scored the other $3$.  In the same way, we can $subtract$ $3$ from each of Norway's for and against totals to figure out the score in the Norway-Netherlands game.

France beat the Netherlands $4-3,$ and Norway lost to the Netherlands $1-2.$

The crux of this problem is that each team played only two games, so once you know the score in one of its games, you can figure out the score in the other.

Comment: Your approach is faster than the other methods, but I'm still struggling on how you get there. In other words, in a problem like this, what I want to do is find the number of goals between the teams lets say second and third so I could compare it with the first. In this case the remaining goals which don't account for Netherlands must involve the other two.

Comment: Since the problem mentions that it was a tie, so it should be understood as half of that value hence $3$. Since France has $GF=7$ this meant for the game involving Netherlands (the only left choice) $x+3=7$ therefore $x=4$ and $GA$ is $y+3=6$ so $y=3$.

Comment: Conversely for Norway in the match against Netherlands, from the result in $GF$ is $x+3=4$ so $x=1$ and $GA$ is $y+3=5$ so $y=2$ Finally $1$ accounts for the goal made in that match and the other $2$ the received from Netherlands, so the result was $2-1$. I've just hope to be understanding it right. Am I?. I had to use the $x$ and $y$ variables as an aid to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that you are right.  Since you had a little trouble following my answer, I'll add a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Ab$ represent the number of goals made by $A$ against team $b$ and use the abbreviations $L,F,W$ to refer to Nether**l**ands, **F**rance, and Nor**w**ay respectively.  So $Lf$ is the number of goals scored by Netherlands against France for example.

We are told from the *table* the following information:

$$\begin{cases} Lf+Lw = 5\\Fl+Wl = 5\\ Fl+Fw = 7\\Lf+Wf = 6\\Wf+Wl = 4\\Fw + Lw = 5\end{cases}$$

We are also told one additional piece of information.  The match between France and Norway ended in a draw, giving us the equation:

$$Fw -Wf= 0$$

Including this last equation, this is a linear system of seven equations with six unknowns.  We may then apply [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) to find the solution(s) if any exist.

Letting the columns be in the order $Lf, Lw, Fl, Fw, Wf, Wl$ we have the augmented matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}1&1&0&0&0&0&5\\0&0&1&0&0&1&5\\0&0&1&1&0&0&7\\1&0&0&0&1&0&6\\0&0&0&0&1&1&4\\0&1&0&1&0&0&5\\0&0&0&1&-1&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

[After row reducing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1,1,0,0,0,0,5%7D,%7B0,0,1,0,0,1,5%7D,%7B0,0,1,1,0,0,7%7D,%7B1,0,0,0,1,0,6%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,1,1,4%7D,%7B0,1,0,1,0,0,5%7D,%7B0,0,0,1,-1,0,0%7D%7D) this leaves us with the augmented matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}1&0&0&0&0&0&3\\0&1&0&0&0&0&2\\0&0&1&0&0&0&4\\0&0&0&1&0&0&3\\0&0&0&0&1&0&3\\0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

From this, we can read out the values for each of $Lf,Lw,\cdots$ and we learn that the result of the match between Netherlands and Norway was $2$-$1$

Comment: Aren't there 7 equations with the drawn game included? Do you need that one? In this particular case or in general for problem like this?

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm a bit confused with the upper and lowercase variables you used. Why should be represented $Ab$ the number of goals?. Why the product?. Does it mean a convertion factor?. Let's say $L\times \textrm{goals made against france} + L \times \textrm{goals made against norway}=5$

Comment: @JMoravitz But what then is the uppercase (also goals?), but this wouldn't produce a squared?. This part is where I'm stuck at. Hope you can help me to clear out this doubt.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I did not intend it to be interpreted as a product, but rather as a variable represented by two letters.  Just like how you might use equations like $\text{Speed}\times \text{Time}=\text{Distance}$ where the variable is written like $\text{Speed}$ rather than shortening to a single character like $s\times t = d$.  There is no  multiplication happening in my work above, just two-letter variable names.

Comment: @JMoravitz Upon reading again your answer it seems that this was the intended meaning. Sorry I'm slow at catching up these things. But why using two letters?. Because the two digits would represent together the result of the match?.

Comment: @Ned My first revision did not include the drawn game initially and went back to include it after recognizing it was necessary information.  I had apparently forgotten to rewrite the sentence, it is indeed a linear system of seven equations with six unknowns.  In some similar problems we might have been able to get away with only using six equations rather than all seven, but in this particular case you can see that regardless what the number of goals were the matrix formed using only the initial six equations is non-invertible meaning that it is not enough information by itself to solve.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Why two letters?  So that I can talk about the goals scored by Netherlands against France in a conveniently named variable and so I can remember when looking at the variable name what it meant.  If I named things $a,b,c,d,e,f$ then I would need to constantly refer back to my chart to remember which variable corresponded to which meaning.  Here it is clear, $Lf$ is the number of goals scored by nether**L**ands against **F**rance.  If this was instead named $c$, I wouldn't know what $c$ meant an hour later when revisiting the problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz I had to look in the last matrix to figure out, you used two letters to state the order right?. I hope to be understanding correctly. Since there aren't any two digit results. From the matrix it can be seen $Lw=2$ and $Wl=1$ hence the result from that match would be $2:1$ is that right?.

Comment: @JMoravitz Why the last equation is a difference and not a sum as the others?. I'm still stuck at this part. Because it meant that the number of goals each one made was the same (hence draw) so it comes from $Fw=Wf$?. Is this the reason?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Yes, exactly.  The game is a draw means that both teams scored the same number of goals against eachother, which means that $Fw=Wf$.  If we move that all to the same side of the equation so as to be in the standard format (variables all on one side, constants all on the other) this would be $Fw-Wf=0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I see, rows 1,3,5 add up to the same as rows 2,4,6 and that will happen with any such 3 team round robin, so the linear system won't have a unique solution. However, the solution will be a (translate of a) one dimensional subspace, and given that the desired solution must consist of 6 non-negative integers, I wonder if there are any other solutions that could be actual soccer scores -- in this case or in general?

Comment: OK, without the drawn game condition there are 4 feasible solutions, with $Wl$ possibly being 0, 1, 2, or 3. The coefficients all being 1 means varying the free variable over integers keeps the others equal to integers, so the only restriction is that all must be non-negative. If $Wl$ >= 4, then $Lw = 3-Wl $ would be negative.